# Why does the eclipse IDE give me terminated error when I try to write a file?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileWriterDemo {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String source = "Now is the time for all good men\n" +
                    " to come to aid of their country\n" +
                    " and pay their due taxes";

    char buffer[] = new char[source.length()];
    source.getChars(0, source.length(), buffer, 0);

    FileWriter f0 = new FileWriter("file1.txt");
    FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter("file2.txt");
    FileWriter f2 = new FileWriter("file3.txt");

    try{
        for(int i =0; i<buffer.length; i+=2){
            f0.write(buffer[i]);
        }

        f1.write(buffer);
        f2.write(buffer, buffer.length-buffer.length/4, buffer.length/4);

    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("An I/O Error occured.");
    }
}
```

}

This is the program that I've written. I copied this program exactly from a book, but my IDE (Eclipse) keeps giving me  message. This same problem is encountered when I try to use FileOutputStream class object to create a file and write to it.

Here's an image

Comment: Are you sure it's an *error* rather than the program just completing?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Also, you might want to use `e.printStackTrace` instead of `System.out.println(...)` in your catch block.

Comment: If you would copy paste the message/error that you are seeing, it would greatly help us to help you, and we don't have to make a guess as to what is happening on your computer.

Comment: It's not an error per say, but I get <terminated>.... in the title of my console tab, with no output whatsoever.

Comment: <terminated> means that the program terminated.  Judging from your program, nothing should print if it terminates successfully.

Comment: in that case how do I view the contents of those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means the program completed, and in your case probably sucesfully, since it didnt print anything on console.

Just check the contents of `file1.txt , file2.txt and file3.txt` to see if the program was successful

Comment: I checked each of the files. All of them are mysteriously empty

Comment: try doing f0.flush(); f1.flush(); f2.flush();

Comment: Flushing actually flushes the data to underlying layers

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you please explain the mechanism of this. Also, if I want to output the files in the console, should I create FileReader objects?

Comment: When you call write() it only writes the data to its buffers not to the file. So you need to call flush() to force write to underlying filesystem. There is an excpetion that if the buffers get filled, it automatically flushes in to the file